# In Brax, how can I increase the frequency of access to the parameter values? (Ideally for every time step)

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm using the code provided by the [brax tutorial](https://github.com/google/brax/blob/main/notebooks/training.ipynb) with Ant + PPO:

```
train_fn = {
  'ant': functools.partial(ppo.train,
                           num_timesteps= 1_000_000,
                           num_evals=10,
                           reward_scaling=10,
                           episode_length=1000,
                           normalize_observations=True,
                           action_repeat=1,
                           unroll_length=5,
                           num_minibatches=32,
                           num_updates_per_batch=4,
                           discounting=0.97,
                           learning_rate=3e-4,
                           entropy_cost=1e-2,
                           num_envs=4096,
                           batch_size=2048,
                           seed=1),
}[env_name]

def progress(num_steps, metrics):
  times.append(datetime.now())
  x_data.append(num_steps)
  y_data.append(metrics['eval/episode_reward'])
  y_data_err.append(metrics['eval/episode_reward_std'])
  clear_output(wait=True)
  plt.xlim([0, train_fn.keywords['num_timesteps']])
  plt.ylim([min_y, max_y])
  plt.xlabel('timesteps')
  plt.ylabel('reward per episode')
  plt.errorbar(x_data, y_data, yerr=y_data_err)
  plt.show()

def policy_params(num_steps, make_policy, params):
  model.save_params('/tmp/params', params)
  params = model.load_params('/tmp/params')
  print('2. params \n', params[0:1])
  steps.append(num_steps)
  mu_data.append(params[0].mean)
  std_data.append(params[0].std)
  var_data.append(params[0].summed_variance)

make_inference_fn, params, _ = train_fn(environment=env,
                                        progress_fn=progress,
                                        policy_params_fn=policy_params)

print(f'time to jit: {times[1] - times[0]}')
print(f'time to train: {times[-1] - times[1]}')

print(steps)
```

The issue I'm having is that with the function policy_params I only get the parameter values for a small number of intervals/checkpoints, those points are:

```
print(steps)
[327680, 655360, 983040, 1310720, 1638400, 1966080, 2293760, 2621440, 2949120]
```

How can I change the frequency with which parameter values are stored and/or accessed by the user-defined callback function 'policy_params_fn'? I varied num_steps and this doesn't control the frequency.